# Redisplay the new data in OpenGL without re-running the program

Tags: c++, opengl

For example, in my "test.txt" file

```
2 3
2 4
2 5
```

When I show in my OpenGL/C++ ( I'm using graph to represent it )
so when I go to my "test.txt" file and change some value and want to see
the new graph with new data without stop and recompile back.
isn't any way to refresh it?

NOTE: `glutPostRedisplay()` not working.

Thanks

```
void drawScene(void)
{
    readFile(inFile);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(0.0,0.0,0.0);

    histogram();
    linestrip();
    piechart2012();
    piechart2013();

    glFlush();
    //readFile(inFile);
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    glutInit (&argc, argv); /* Initialise OpenGL */
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(800,600);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);

    printInteraction();


    glutCreateWindow ( "square.cpp" ); /* Create the window */
    glutDisplayFunc (drawScene); /* Register the "display" function */
    glutReshapeFunc(resize);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyInput);
    setup();
    glutMainLoop(); /* Enter the OpenGL main loop */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you'll need to read test.txt again completely

Comment: You can periodically poll the timestamp of the file and update your data when it changes. Alternatively, there's an operating system specific way of receiving file system notifications. What do you mean by "not working"? Do you receive an error? If it's not doing what you expect, there's no way for us to help you unless you post the relevant code (and any error messages).

Comment: no any error message. just my file keep loading the old data. above is my code when read

Comment: Did you try turning it of and on again? :P Seriously, just call `readFile()` somewhere inside `main()` and the file will be reloaded once your program starts.

Comment: @ChrisTeh do you make sure to close and re-open the file after it's changed?